# What is the 'condition' type for react component children props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using Material UI for React.
I have a 'TabHeader' component that takes a list of 'Tab' components.

Those are defined as follow:

```
children?: React.ReactElement<TabProps>[];
```

Example of how I use them:

```
<TabHeader>
   <Tab value="val1" label="Label1" />
   <Tab value="val2" label="Label2" />
</TabHeader>
```

It's all working until here.

Some 'Tab' are conditional, so I would like to wrap them as follow:

```
{someCondition && <Tab value="val1" label="Label1" />}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement...
```

How can I define a type that takes the Tabs or false (if it's true it doesn't trigger that error).

Comment: Can you add more code for understanding? It's hard to tell from this.

Comment: How exactly are they conditional, isn't `children?: ...` prop conditional for that exact purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Define children as an array of 'element' or 'boolean' (false):

```
children?: (React.ReactElement<TabProps> | boolean)[];
```

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript error comes because you're passing in `false` as a child element, but `false` doesn't match the type you provided for `children`. Since `false` doesn't satisfy the type of `React.ReactElement<TabProps>`, TypeScript is telling you that the types are incompatible.

To achieve this you need to accept false as a child element. The type definition for that might look like

```
children?: (React.ReactElement<TabProps> | false)[];
```

---

More context on JS and type definitions:

When `someCondition` is false, it will return false. When `someCondition` is true, it will return the result of the last condition - in this case the JSX element `<Tab>`.

```
{someCondition && <Tab value="val1" label="Label1" />}
```

This is perhaps more easily understood by looking at the equivalent ternary logic:

```
{someCondition
  ? <Tab value="val1" label="Label1" />
  : false
}
```

Marking children as optional (`children?`) is allowing you to either pass all valid children, or none at all. So something like this would work

```
<Tab value="val1" label="Label1" ></Tab>
```

And so would

```
<TabHeader>
   <Tab value="val1" label="Label1" />
   <Tab value="val2" label="Label2" />
</TabHeader>
```

But the following doesn't work because the type could be false. The following JSX:

```
<TabHeader>
   <Tab value="val1" label="Label1" />
   {someCondition && <Tab value="val2" label="Label2" />}
   <Tab value="val3" label="Label3" />
</TabHeader>
```

will pass children as:

```
[
  <Tab value="val1" label="Label1" />,
  false,
  <Tab value="val3" label="Label3" />,
]
```

when `someCondition` is false.